# What is this mystery 'j' in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was in the rails console, accidentally typed in the letter `j` and hit enter and it returned `nil`.

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
[6] pry(main)> j
=> nil
[1] pry(main)> j.nil?
=> true
```

Google didn't get me anywhere. Anybody know what this mysterious `j` is and what its purpose is? Just curious.

Comment: I know that `j` is short for `escape_javascript`, a method which allows you to insert partials in `.js.erb` files. If you call that with no params, it might return nil.

Comment: There are also `p` and `y`.

Comment: @roob - yep, `y` method comes from `YAML` module, can be accessed in pure ruby without any gems after `require 'yaml'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always found the source of given method using `source_location`:

```
method(:j).source_location
```

Or even its exact definition with pry (or `method_source` gem):

```
method(:j).source
```

Result:

```
def j(*objs)
  objs.each do |obj|
    puts JSON::generate(obj, :allow_nan => true, :max_nesting => false)
  end
  nil
end
```

`j` is a method coming from JSON library (which is adding this method to  `Kernel` module so it is accessible in irb), and it is responsible for displaying given arguments as JSON objects:

```
j(hello: :world) 
  #=> {"hello":"world"}
  nil
```

Rails by default require `json` library so it is available straight away. In pure IRB, you need to `require 'json'` to have an access to it.

It accepts any number of arguments, so `j` returns nil without printing anything. It is equivalent of `p` method, just uses json instead of `inspect` result.

Comment: This is way helpful. Great answer. Also, I didn't know I could do this: `method(:j).source`. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: @RyanRebo - Well, normally you can't, you need to ho run pry session or require `method_source` gem to be able to do this. `source_location` is however available even in the most pure irb.